# SVN commit fails with error message

Tags: .net, svn, tortoisesvn, repository

I have modified some file and after modifying the file I am trying to commit the file in repository but I am getting error while committing the file here is stack trace of error.

> Error: Commit failed (details follow):
>
> Error: MERGE request failed on '/qr/QR_MAVEN/quickres/branches/EMD_IGT'
>
> Error: Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output:
>
> Error: Your log message does not contain a CRUCIBLE review identifier (or bad format used)
>
> Error: The CRUCIBLE review identifier should be in the line of the log message.
>
> Error: Proper commit message should contain:"+ review "
>
> Error: for quickres commit message should
>
> Error: contain "+review qd"
>
> Error: to add an existed review please specify the review number "+review qd-"

**Environment**

> OS : Windows
>
> Repos: SVN
>
> Client:TortoiseSVN.

Every thing was working till yesterday. What could be the cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pre-commit` hook of your repository fired. Basically, it is a way to allow repository maintainers to assure a certain set of criteria about your checkin to be met, before the commit actually takes place:

> Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output:

Actually, it tells you everything you (should) need to know right in the message - which is not a "stacktrace" by the way, but just a multiline message of some sort (I reformatted it for easier reading):

> Your log message does not contain a CRUCIBLE review identifier (or bad format used)
>
> The CRUCIBLE review identifier should be in the line of the log message.
>   Proper commit message should contain:"+ review " for quickres commit message should contain "+review qd" to add an existed review please specify the review number "+review qd-".

So in your case, it wants you to specify a [Crucible](http://www.atlassian.com/software/crucible/overview) code review identifier in the log message. It even gives you a hint what to do in the last sentence.

Comment: Thanks for reply can you add a sample message please

Comment: @Real You need to check that with the administrator of your repository. We don't know the setup of your repository, nor the exact requirements of your pre-commit hook.

Comment: Thanks for help I have just intimated to our administrator. If you are true then, it is very disappointing, without informing the team how the decision is taken.